# Any way to get total number of cases in nosetests?

Tags: python, nosetests

Need total number of testcases including error.In nosetests ,the result always shows in following manner.
    `Ran 5 cases (errors=3)`
These 5 cases does not include 3 errored cases. Is there any way to get errored cases included in total Ran count?

Comment: from my experience those 5 cases do include errors. If you need to get the total number of tests you can always use `--collect-only` command line flag to dry-run all the tests.

Comment: `collect-only` won't execute the cases right?

Comment: No, it will not execute anything.

Comment: So I need to have a way in which once the testcases are executed , it will give he final number including the errored once. By error testcases I meant testcases that got errored in setup section and hence are not included in "Ran" count

Comment: in django it will create the db wasting your time. unless --keepdb

Comment: `Ran 5 cases (errors=3)` does include the failed tests. `Total=5 , Failed=3`

Comment: It includes failed cases but not error cases.